# i have a datagridview and its editable i can open my form, edit and then close it, i want to see the new edited data after open it again

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have a button ( edit ) when i click on it, new data will apply in my data grid view but after closing and opening the form my cell ( Page Description ) is empty ( i want to see the last edited data in it ) it would be better to know that i dont have any data base and i have my local variables

private void btn_editPgStruct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
bool status = true;
try
{
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
string des_pageMacroName = string.Empty;
string des_pageNomination = string.Empty;

```
         if (CurrentLanguage.CultureName == "en")
         {
             des_pageMacroName = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PageMacroName"].Value == null ? string.Empty : dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PageMacroName"].Value.ToString();
             des_pageNomination = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Page Description"].Value == null ? string.Empty : dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Page Description"].Value.ToString();
         }
         else if (CurrentLanguage.CultureName == "de")
         {
             des_pageMacroName = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Seitenmakroname"].Value == null ? string.Empty : dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Seitenmakroname"].Value.ToString();
             des_pageNomination = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Seitenbeschreibung"].Value == null ? string.Empty : dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Seitenbeschreibung"].Value.ToString();
         }
         
             if (currentPageMacroDM != null)
             {
                 currentPageMacroDM.pageList[currentPageIndex].pageNumber = currentPageIndex + 1;
                 currentPageMacroDM.pageList[currentPageIndex].pageMacroName = des_pageMacroName;
                 currentPageMacroDM.pageList[currentPageIndex].pageNominationName = des_pageNomination;
             }
             else if (currentPageMacroDM == null && currentPageDM != null)
             {
                 currentPageDM.pageNominationName = "@" + des_pageNomination;
                 currentPageDM.pageMacroName = "@" + des_pageMacroName;
             currentPageMacroDM.pageList[i].pageMacroName = des_pageMacroName;
             currentPageMacroDM.pageList[i].pageNominationName = des_pageNomination;
         }

     }
       
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     status = false;
     System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("Error"), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
 }
 finally
 {
     if (status == true)
     {
         System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("EditStructureMessage"), Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("Success"), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
       
         this.Close();
     }
 }
```

}

private void datagridview1_CellEndEdit_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = cell.Value;
}

private void datagridview1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

}